# alert client when live stream is done in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, rtmp, live-streaming

I thought that it was the `NetStream.Play.UnpublishNotify` in the `NetStatusEvent` but that doesn't get fired when I stop the live stream. The onFCUnsubscribe event does get fired, however, I have a 5 second buffer and it doesn't wait for that buffer. It gets that event almost instantly. What is the correct way to alert a user that the stream is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Netstream.Play.Stop` is fired when the stream finishes playing.

Have a look here.
http://flash-reference.icod.de/NetStream.html

Comment: that gets fired on a normal stream. In my case, this is a live stream and stop doesnt get fired..in face nothing in the `NetStatusEvent` gets fired when I stop publishing the live URL

Comment: Then you should be looking on `onPlayStatus` Event . http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onPlayStatus

Comment: it looks like adding `ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onNetStatus);` to `NetStatus` versus `NetConnection` is more accurate